# Regenerate vector of randoms in Python

Tags: python, random

I am trying to generate and regenerate vector of random normals

I want to be able to achieve the following by generating random normal matrix of size 100x3 and random normals having mean 0 and sd 1:

```
seed1 = '123'
seed2 = 'asd'
randMatrixrows = 100
randMatrixcols = 3
mu = 0
sd = 1

normRand1 = rekina_normRandomGenerator( seed1, randMatrixrows, randMatrixcols, mu, sd ) #normRand1 is of size 100x3
normRand2 = rekina_normRandomGenerator( seed2, randMatrixrows, randMatrixcols, mu, sd )
normRand3 = rekina_normRandomGenerator( seed1, randMatrixrows, randMatrixcols, mu, sd )
normRand4 = rekina_normRandomGenerator( seed2, randMatrixrows, randMatrixcols, mu, sd )

err1 = normRand1 - normRand3
err2 = normRand2 - normRand4
```

Each element of err1 and err2 should be 0

I have tried to read also but being new to Python I am totally lost with the implementation. I was expecting a simple implementation to show how to use the CBRNG.

Comment: I don't know much about reikna, but every time you generate a random thing, won't it be different? Why do you need err1 and err3 to be 0?

Comment: @Sagar https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator, seeding controls given "random" numbers, which are completely deterministic. Having repeatable "random" numbers can be very useful in testing etc.

Comment: Thanks @Ilja will go through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial assumption that you have to use [`reikna.cbrng.CBRNG`](http://reikna.publicfields.net/en/latest/api/computations.html#reikna.cbrng.CBRNG) is correct. It seems it offers a multitude of [sources of pseudo randomness](http://reikna.publicfields.net/en/latest/api/computations.html#reikna.cbrng.bijections.Bijection) – based on counter-based RNGs – and [distributions](http://reikna.publicfields.net/en/latest/api/computations.html#reikna.cbrng.samplers.Sampler), which can be confusing. It also offers [shortcuts](http://reikna.publicfields.net/en/latest/api/computations.html#reikna.cbrng.CBRNG.sampler_name) for creating random number generators with given distribution.

```
from reikna.core import Type
from reikna.cbrng import CBRNG
from reikna.cluda import any_api
import numpy as np

# Get any supported API for this system, or an exception    
_api = any_api()
# The global CLUDA Thread, wrapping context, shared by all
# reikna_norm_rng's
_thr = _api.Thread.create()


def reikna_norm_rng(seed, rows, cols, mean, std,
                    dtype=np.float32,
                    generators_dim=1):
    """
    A do-all generator function for creating a new Computation
    returning a stream of pseudorandom number arrays.
    """
    # The Type of the output array
    randoms_arr = Type(dtype, (rows, cols))
    # Shortcut for creating a Sampler for normally distributed
    # random numbers
    rng = CBRNG.normal_bm(randoms_arr=randoms_arr,
                          generators_dim=generators_dim,
                          sampler_kwds=dict(mean=mean, std=std),
                          # Reikna expects a positive integer. This is a 
                          # quick and *dirty* solution.
                          seed=abs(hash(seed)))
    compiled_comp = rng.compile(_thr)
    # RNG "state"
    counters = _thr.to_device(rng.create_counters())
    # Output array
    randoms = _thr.empty_like(compiled_comp.parameter.randoms)

    while True:
        compiled_comp(counters, randoms)
        yield randoms.get()
```

To see it in action add:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    seed1 = '123'
    seed2 = 'asd'
    rows, cols = 100, 3
    mu, sd = 0, 1

    # This will create a new RNG, take 1 result and throw the RNG away
    r1 = next(reikna_norm_rng(seed1, rows, cols, mu, sd))
    r2 = next(reikna_norm_rng(seed2, rows, cols, mu, sd))
    r3 = next(reikna_norm_rng(seed1, rows, cols, mu, sd))
    r4 = next(reikna_norm_rng(seed2, rows, cols, mu, sd))

    err1 = r1 - r3
    err2 = r2 - r4

    print("all(err1 == 0):", np.all(err1 == 0))
    print("all(err2 == 0):", np.all(err2 == 0))
```

> I also want to make sure that randoms generated using the two different seeds have no correlation.

This depends on the quality of the implementation. Here's how 2 sets of numbers with seeds *0* and *1* plotted out:

```
rng1 = reikna_norm_rng(0, 100, 10000, 0, 1)
rng2 = reikna_norm_rng(1, 100, 10000, 0, 1)
A = next(rng1)
B = next(rng2)
A_r = A.ravel()
B_r = B.ravel()
for i in range(0, A_r.size, 1000):
    plot(A_r[i:i+1000], B_r[i:i+1000], 'b.')
```

[image: plot(A, B)]

**Disclaimer**

This is my first run in with *reikna*. The above code may not release resources timely and/or leak like a sieve. It uses a global [`Thread`](http://reikna.publicfields.net/en/latest/api/cluda.html#reikna.cluda.api.Thread), which may not be what you want in a larger application.

**PS**

```
np.random.seed(seed)
np.random.normal(0, 1, (100, 3))
```

also produces arrays of normally distributed random numbers with shape *(100, 3)*, though it does not employ the GPU.

Comment: "The above code may not release resources timely and/or leak like a sieve. It uses a global Thread, which may not be what you want in a larger application." What does this statement mean.

Comment: In general I trust python objects to release resources etc. when they get gc'd, but this GPU stuff is a bit alien to me and so I'm not entirely sure, if you're supposed to manually release those buffers. Probably not.

Comment: In a larger app you'd probably refactor `reikna_norm_rng` to take an app provided Thread instance instead of a module scope global. Makes testing easier and it'd be more modular in general.

Comment: @Zanam A note on `seed=abs(hash(seed))`: numpy 1.11 has changed seed handling and instead of silently reducing given seed modulo `2**32` it'll raise an exception (ran in to this just now). So either the seeding has to be changed to a proper 32bit seed generation from given seed, or just do a `seed=abs(hash(seed)) % 2**32` yourself, if it isn't that critical. Reikna uses numpy's PRNG's to create the keys for the CBRNG.